# Solution of ODE vanishes between two points (Application of Sturm Comparison).

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a problem below

> Let  $r \in C\left([0,\infty)\right)$  be a function such that  $r(t)
> >  m^2 >0$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $y$ be a solution of the ODE $$y'' +r(t)y = 0, ~t\geq0$$ Show that $y$ vanishes at least one
> point on each of the interval $$I_n = \left( \frac{n\pi}m,\
>  \frac{(n+1)\pi}m \right),  n \in \mathbb{N}$$

We thought to use Sturm Comparison theorem to do this. But for that we will have to prove that for above inequality, we will of to show that there exists one non zero solution at each $\frac{n\pi}m $. But this need not be necessary.
Can you tell me if this is the right path and if yes then what I am missing here in order to reach the solution?

Comment: You compare against the function $u(t)=\sin(mt)$ as one solution of $u''+m^2u=0$. As the function with the higher (if variable) frequency, $y$ will have at least one zero-crossing in-between each pair of roots of $u$. This is formalized by the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem. Now are you to prove the theorem in this special situation or just apply it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem really is just to manage the possibility of roots at the interval end-points:

Over the fixed interval $[\frac{n\pi}m,\frac{(n+1)\pi}m]$ the function $r$ has a minimum that is strictly larger than $m^2$, say $(m+\varepsilon)^2$. Now compare against solutions of
$$
u''+(m+ε)^2u=0
$$
and pick one $u(t)=\sin((m+ε)t+\phi)$ that has roots at $\frac{n\pi}m+\delta$ and $\frac{(n+1)\pi}m-\delta$, where $δ>0$ exists and depends on $ε$, it is solution of $\frac1m-2δ=\frac1{m+ε}$

By the comparison theorem $y$ necessarily has at least one root in $[\frac{n\pi}m+\delta,\frac{(n+1)\pi}m-\delta]$ and thus also inside the open interval $(\frac{n\pi}m,\frac{(n+1)\pi}m)$.